# Rails if statement in form with simple_form and HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

I have the following code in form that automatically puts the position of the object into input, using the if statement to eliminate this from happening when user edits.

```
- if @collection_page.new_record?
  = f.input :position, :label => "Display order:", input_html: { value: Spree::CollectionPage.last.position + 1 }
- else
  = f.input :position, :label => "Display order:"
```

I'm having trouble when there are no records and creating the first one, I get the usual nil class error.

```
undefined method `position' for nil:NilClass
```

Which makes sense because I don't have any records yet.

So just need to put a little more logic in there.

I tried:

```
- if @collection_page.new_record? || Spree::CollectionPage.last.position.present? # and @collection_page.last.position.present?
```

Without success

Looking for a clean way to achieve this, thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How will the `.last.position` ever be defined if it is a new record?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: So I'm confused why you make that the value for the input if it isn't defined

Comment: Maybe I can check if Spree::CollectionPage has no records and then execute

Comment: It's defined after first record is created

Comment: Yes, do `if @collection_page.new_record? && Spree::CollectionPage.last.present?`

Comment: that makes sense! I'll try it shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used an or statement. `||` is or, while `&&` is and. Also, you're checking if `last.position.present?` which will not work if `last` is not present.

Try `if @collection_page.new_record? && Spree::CollectionPage.last.present?`